# How to identify popular items in time-series data

Tags: time-series, probability, distributions

I have a dataset which contains time-series events in which each event is an item chosen from a unknowably large set of items. For example, let's say that the data entries are each music playlist entries in which a particular song was played at a particular time. Some of the songs will be quite uncommon and only played once in the entire dataset; some will be regular favorites with a consistent baseline popularity (as likelihood to be played); and some will be fads which are disproportionately popular for a few weeks or months. (Some might also be seasonal, where they are fads which repeat regularly, but for the purposes of my analysis I'm willing to ignore this aspect.)

My mental model is that every item has a certain chance to be randomly selected, and that chance varies over time in a smoothly differentiable fashion.

I would like to identify what the "hot" items in any time span are, when compared to times outside of that timespan.

A naive approach would be to just look at the fraction of times that each item is selected in my chosen time span and compare it to the likelihood of that item over my entire dataset, but this would suffer from low-frequency outliers (e.g. if a particular song was only played once in the entire dataset, it would be a leader in popularity for any time span which contained that single play).

My intuition is that if you have an item which occurs at 1% likelihood over many instances, but is 5% for a month, that's a stronger signal of being "hot" than something which has its sole occurrence in that month.

I think my question has something to do with how I can infer the likely window of underlying probability of these events through observation of the outcomes, and with the belief that this underlying probability varies smoothly over time, identify items with underlying probability peaks (hotness) from event observation.

I'm sure this is a well-studied question with a standard textbook answer, but I have little domain knowledge and, without knowing the term of the art, can't find the simple explanation. I looked at autocorrelation a bit, but couldn't figure out how to make use of what I read. It's presumably relevant for identifying trends in other time series about selection from large sets (e.g. popularity of items in online shopping, choice of baby names, etc.).

If it's relevant, I'm going to be implementing this analysis in Python for predefined time ranges (e.g. "What were the most popular songs for March 2021"), and I'm OK with an approximate answer (given that my data is random at its root in the first place, there is no certain result).

Comment: I don't grasp the objection about "low-frequency outliers:" during a sufficiently small time window, *every* selected item is "hot" (channeling Warhol's "15 minutes of fame" quotation).  Why is that a problem?

Comment: I attempted to expand in the question, since my response was too long for a comment. My mental model is that I'm looking to infer the shift over time in the underlying probability of events, based on my observation of outcomes. A single event outcome doesn't convey a lot of evidence about underlying probability or how it may have shifted.